# controling right and left wheels using ROS

Tags: ros, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear guys,

Can anyone help me, i just follow a tutorial to make "Differential Drive Robot" from this link:

https://www.generationrobots.com/blog/en/2015/02/robotic-simulation-scenarios-with-gazebo-and-ros/

in the tutorial, Mobile robot models can be moved using cmd_vel (by controlling linear,x and angular.z). How can i control right and left wheels based on the trajectory? Im newbie :(

Thank you in advance

this is my code:

```
ros::Publisher pLeft = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Float64>("/my_robot/leftWheel_effort_controller/command",1);

ros::Publisher pRight = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Float64>("/my_robot/rightWheel_effort_controller/command",1);


std_msgs::Float64 stdMessage;

pLeft.publish(stdMessage);

pRight.publish(stdMessage);
```

But, it do nothing :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279465/controling-right-and-left-wheels-using-ros/) by [JossiChrist](https://answers.ros.org/users/33238/jossichrist/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-10**:
Welcome! What have you tried so far (an example of your code please)? Showing that you've put forth some effort is likely to increase your chances of getting help with this.

**Comment by [JossiChrist](https://answers.ros.org/users/33238/jossichrist/) on 2018-01-12**:
i have showed the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not familiar with this exact robot, but I can see some problems.

you're creating two message objects, but you're setting their values. Each message should contain the velocity (effort) that you want each wheel to move out. The code you have shown is sending values of zero, which may be why the robot isn't moving.

Is there a reason why you're not using the cmd_vel topic? It's usually much easier to use this to drive a robot like this.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-12**:
Like @PeteBlackerThe3rd says, when you instantiate the message all of the numerical fields will be `0`. The exception to this is when default values are provided in the message definition, but I'm not aware of any `std_msgs` that provide non-zero default values.

**Comment by [JossiChrist](https://answers.ros.org/users/33238/jossichrist/) on 2018-01-14**:
i have already filled the std::Message with some data. but it didnt move.

when i did rostpclist:

/my_robot/leftWheel_effort_controller/command
/my_robot/rightWheel_effort_controller/command

this command also dont work:
rostopic pub -1 /my_robot/rightWheel_effort_controller/command ...

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-01-14**:
Did you change the name of the robot from that used in the tutorial? You're using **my_robot** but the example uses **mybot**? So the command should be:

```
rostopic pub -1 /mybot/leftWheel_effort_controller/command std_msgs/Float64 "data: 1.5"
```